# Can closure compiler use chaining as a minification technique?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, chaining

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @exclude_default_externs true
// @js_externs var console = {log: function(){}};
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/** @constructor */
function Test(){};
Test.prototype['action'] = function(){ 
  console.log('Hello');
  return this;
}

var test = new Test();
```

If I add the line:

```
test['action']()['action']()['action']();
```

and compile it I get this size:

```
113 bytes (101 bytes gzipped)
```

If I replace that line with this equivalent code:

```
test['action']();
test['action']();
test['action']();
```

I get this size:

```
123 bytes (108 bytes gzipped)
```

I was hoping that closure compiler would recognize that, since my function returns `this`, it can chain the calls to `action` (how it's done in the first test) and get the smaller size result. Is there a way to annotate the above code so that Closure Compiler is able to make this optimization?

**Note:** The difference in size is caused by the chaining. The difference in the output is as follows:

With chaining:

```
(new a).action().action().action();
```

Without chaining:

```
var b=new a;b.action();b.action();b.action();
```

Comment: Playing with the code I've noticed that the ['member'] syntax confuses the compiler. Lets say I added /** @return {string} */Test.prototype['nooo']=function Then call var t=new Test(); t['nooo']()['action']() There are no errors or warnings when compiling. But defining nooo and action as Test.prototype.nooo will give a compile warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a compiler pass for this:

https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainCalls.java

It isn't enabled by default, however.  It didn't provide any saving for the projects that we tested it with but you could try enabling it.  It is controlled by the "CompilerOptions#setChainCalls" method in the Compiler's Java API.

Comment: Thanks John, is there a way to enable this using a comment at the top of the source file when compiling using closure-compiler.appspot.com?  Something like `// @set_chain_calls true`?

Comment: No - custom passes are only available via the Java API. There is no way to enable that pass on the web service.